# I can't alter my list generated from a textfile, how would I go about doing this? Python 3.x.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
file = open('Names.txt', 'r')
for lines in file:
    names = lines.split()
    names_list = [item.strip(',') for item in names]
    reformattedName = (names_list[1:]+names_list[0])
    print(reformattedName)
```

This is what I have so far.

With the text file being:

```
Neuman,     Alfred E.
Stevenson, Robert Lewis     
Lewis, C.S.   
Doe, Jane   
Bush, George Herbert   Walker
```

I'm trying to rearrange it to look like:

```
Alfred E. Nueman
Robert Lewis Stevenson
C.S. Lewis
Jane Doe
George Herbert Walker Bush
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to concatenate lists with lists, not a string with a list:

```
reformattedName = names_list[1:] + names_list[:1]
```

or perhaps you wanted to rejoin the elements into a string again:

```
reformattedName = ' '.join(names_list[1:] + names_list[:1])
```